# Ubuntu 18.04 no ethernet nor wifi connection exactly after installation of drivers (lenovo nvidia drivers)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless, internet, ethernet

I used the command "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" to install some new drivers (for being able to connect a second monitor to my ubuntu) and it worked. However after that both wifi and ethernet doesnt work at all and have completely no internet. The result of the "sudo lshw -C network" command is the following:
[output of "sudo lshw -C network"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMDY3.png)
I tried some solutions but none of them worked. My laptop is a lenovo legion model with nvidia graphic card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a kernel upgrade was interrupted.

Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu. Network should start working.

Then upgrade the system by

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, fixed the issue though I'm back to the problem that can't connect to the second monitor. Do you think I should try again the command sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall or it will create the same problems? And if it does can I come again to this kernel or will this be also ruined?

Comment: It shouldn't create problems if it is not interrupted.